# Running iOS on physical device from expo-cli

Tags: ios, expo, podfile

I am trying to run iOS on a physical device (iPhone 12 with iOS 16) and when running `react-native run-ios --device OrderDevice` I get following error.

```
Details:  (null) deviceType from #####-000B44A90CE1001E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: ##########>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x6######5c180>{number = 2, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

With `xcrun xctrace list devices` I can see following list.

```
Carlos’s MacBook Pro (DBCC450D-C508-5A34-9104-#####)
OrderDevice (16.1) (#######-000B44A90CE1001E)

== Simulators ==
iPad (9th generation) Simulator (16.0) (A1BE92DD-BA33-4727-83EB-###########)
iPad Air (5th generation) Simulator (16.0) (EE341EFA-10C9-4388-B7AC-########)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) Simulator (16.0) (ED21E4AB-90F1-48CB-A2D0-########)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) Simulator (16.0) (C7D3BA35-E429-45C7-B969-C2B9C3CC8536)
iPad mini (6th generation) Simulator (16.0) (FEFC6BC7-BF2B-49C4-84C1-############)
iPhone 12 Simulator (16.0) (84D2B658-25B0-####-8678-4881F6CDF71C)
iPhone 14 Simulator (16.0) (C8085FDC-EFA4-####-B3A6-796FFE7B8842)
iPhone 14 Plus Simulator (16.0) (22E05920-CD4D-####-8E69-FB7F78D6049A)
iPhone 14 Pro Simulator (16.0) (A4BC978D-5F10-4BDB-#####-32768D851141)
iPhone 14 Pro Max Simulator (16.0) (1B4E9233-C61A-4775-#####-04AD4A87210C)
iPhone 8 Simulator (16.0) (328871B7-3E1A-40C4-8893-######)
iPhone SE (3rd generation) Simulator (16.0) (4175625D-####-4CCB-9FFE-72FDE96726CE)
iPhone Xʀ Simulator (16.0) (76971FDA-7485-4A8F-######-33518A1A5B7E)
```

I also tried to run with the udid instead but having the same problem. I read that could be happening because the device is locked but it happens when the device is unlocked too.

When I run on XCode I have no problems. No problems either when running on a simulator, only on the physical device through `expo-cli`.

I read it could be related to the Signing & Capabilities. I tried changing the Podfile to what I found here on this link, but finding same problem.

https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-xcode-archive/issues/299